# How to install properly the latest version of CoffeeScript on Ubuntu (12.04)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, ubuntu-12.04, npm

How to install step by step the latest version of CoffeeScript on Ubuntu 12.04.

The current version of CoffeeScript is 1.6.3

Any comments are be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node version manager).
it helps maintaining several versions of node and switching between them.
it is also less OS intrusive.

after installing nvm, just run 'npm install -g coffeescript' (no sudo is required).

Comment: Yes, I agree with You, but when I wrote this question **nvm** wasn't support the latest version of CoffeeScript so from here the question and answer as well ;) cheers

Answer (score 11):

## Install needed packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev
```

## Install node.js

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git && cd node
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd
```

## Install npm

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

## Install CoffeeScript

```
$ sudo  npm install -g coffeescript
```

Comment: `https://github.com/joyent/node.git` has moved to `https://github.com/nodejs/node`

Comment: Hmmm... This answer is almost a copy of my answer below with some small changes in structure and big header... I think the headers wins...

Answer (score 2):

First, need to update the system and install necessary programs

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev
```

Next, install globally using git the latest stable(master) node and npm

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node/
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now, check the versions of npm and node

```
npm -v     #my version 1.2.25
node -v    #my version v0.11.3-pre
```

After installed npm and node it's time to last piece - CoffeeScript

```
sudo npm install -g coffeescript
```

Check the version and that's all :)

```
coffee -v  #my version 1.6.3
```

Comment: `github.com/joyent/node.git` has moved to `github.com/nodejs/node`